# Is there a callback function for stripe checkout success case?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments, strip

I am using stripe for checkout and i want to create an order in my data base when the chechout succeed.
Do you know how can I run a callback function when the checkout succeed?
All I know is that there is a successUrl for the checkout...

Comment: Which endpoint are you using exactly?

Comment: I am creating a stripe checkout seassion with stripe.checkout.sessions.create() , and then I am redirecting the client to checkoutSession.url

Comment: Maybe just wrap the request with try...catch and look for the success response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use [Checkout Session](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout) to collect payment, customer will be redirected to the `success_url` declared after completing the payment. In addition, Stripe will also send `checkout.session.completed` event via Webhook. I'd recommend listening to `checkout.session.completed` to create and fulfil customer's order: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders

Comment: what if we were to use the embedded table that Stripe Checkout provides? Is there a way to handle it directly from the frontend? https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `EmbeddedCheckout` component, a callback named `onComplete` can be specified.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/custom-redirect-behavior#disable-redirects

```
const App = ({clientSecret}) => {
  const [isComplete, setIsComplete] = useState(false);

  const handleComplete = () => setIsComplete(true);

  return isComplete ? (
    <PurchaseSummary />
  ) : (
    <EmbeddedCheckoutProvider
      stripe={stripePromise}
      options={{
        clientSecret,
        onComplete: handleComplete
      }}
    >
      <EmbeddedCheckout />
    </EmbeddedCheckoutProvider>
  )
}
```